# amCharts chartScrollbar not working when values aren't connected

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I try to configure [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/intraday-data/#) correctly and struggle with the chart scrollbar.
My input data has gaps so I have to set `connect: false` to display those data gaps.

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zt9exqwq/) of a working amStockCharts example and the relevant code snipped.

```
stockGraphs: [{
    id: "g1",
    valueField: "value",
    type: "line",
    connect: false,                // chartScrollBar works if set to true
}],
```

**connect: true**
[image]

**connect: false**
[image]

**Q:** What other settings do I have to change to get both: A working scrollbar and date gaps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your data is one value each day,
but you want the graph to use `minPeriod: "mm"`. This does not seem to work.
Note that you use `usePeriod: "10mm"`, so you have to update this too.
I made your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zt9exqwq/1/) working by removing both.